# dentist use of non kosher products

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Gelfoam made from pork is used by dentists to enhance healing and blood clotting and reduction of likelihood of a dry socket and infection.  It is also less costly to the patient compared to the alternative bone graft.   If nothing is used eventually the socket will heal but it will take longer and with potential painful consequences.

Must the Dentist inform the patient before using any non kosher products?

If patient wasn't asked is the patient entitled to a refund?

Comment: Why would this be subject to kashruth considerations altogether? You aren't eating the grafting substance.

Comment: @Deuteronomy so when a dentist applies something in your mouth, a person can be certain that nothing of the substance will be swallowed?

Comment: Good point. I'm not a dentist and so I cannot answer as to whether that is common in the course of such a surgery. I assume however that the patient had no intent to swallow the substance. Even if the patient did, it would still likely not be an issue according to some (i.e. those that maintain that porcine bones are generally not an issue). And even if it were a problem, the volume certainly wouldn't rise to the level of liability... any way, just my 2 cents. Hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Seems like this wouldn't be an issue as the substance is p'gam. Koshrus considerations don't entitle someone to a refund fyi

Comment: https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/do-dental-products-require-a-hechsher-part-ii-the-kashrut-of-toothpaste-and-mouthwash-year-round-and-pesach-by-dr-ephraim-rudolph-98?format=amp

https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/do-dental-products-require-a-hechsher-part-i-by-dr-ephraim-rudolph-98

Answer (score -1):

Many authorities have ruled (Rav Schachter is one of them) that swallowing medicine that is made of pig is 100% fine

Comment: This requires a bit more details to be correct, for instance in which form (pill vs. liquid). I very very strongly doubt R Schachter would allow swallowing pig-based liquids

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!